# Getting 404 not found when working with docker container nginx uwsgi django

Tags: django, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, uwsgi

I'm having 3 docker containers.

One container has Django with uwsgi and nginx as webserver. I configure inside with 80 port exposed. And later run with 8800:80 mapping in my localhost.

A second container has another Django project with uwsgi and nginx, similar configuration and run with 8801:80 mapping in my localhost.

So right now I can access different Django apps from the container with different ports.

localhost:8800 -> app1

localhost:8801 -> app2

now I create a third container with nginx, which aims to do the reverse proxy.

So I third container has only nginx configuration. Which has something like this:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}



http {
        sendfile on;

        gzip              on;
        gzip_http_version 1.0;
        gzip_proxied      any;
        gzip_min_length   500;
        gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
        gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                          text/comma-separated-values
                          text/javascript
                          application/x-javascript
                          application/atom+xml;

        upstream app1{
            server my_machine_ip:8800;
        }

        upstream app2{
            server my_machine_ip:8801;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        server {
              listen 0.0.0.0:80;

              location /firstapp/ {
                    proxy_pass http://app1/;
                    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
              }

              location /anotherapp/ {
                    proxy_pass http://app2/;
                    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
              }
        }
}
```

Again the container with 80 port expose and I run with port 8888:80 mappings.

Then I have some problems:
When I type localhost:8888/firstapp/, it shows 404 not found. But the URL change to localhost:8888/base/auth/login/?next=/ which it is the login page URL of app1. When I curl with localhost it actually gives my feed back that it is doing the redirection. But the browser just return me a 404 page and I can't login to the project. However, when I type localhost:8800 I can see the login page and login perfectly. It looks like the nginx reverse proxy needs to know the static files to function correctly. So my question:

How the nginx reverse proxy processing the request? My understanding that my current configuration is look like this:

web client <-> nginx reverse proxy <-> nginx webserver <-> uwsgi <-> Django project

My testing of

web client <-> nginx webserver <-> uwsgi <-> Django project

of this chain is totally fine. But when I added the nginx reverse proxy in the chain, then I got the 404 error.

So far as my understanding of this 404 error, I want to know that whether the nginx reverse proxy needs to know where the static files locate in order to function properly. Or I miss something or understanding in configuration.

My goal is to use make different Django projects on the same machine, with same configurations(port 80, so that different projects group can follow the same pattern), and use reverse proxy to type different URI to access different projects.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.13.5
Date: Tue, 17 Oct 2017 14:39:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: /base/auth/login/?next=/
Vary: Cookie
```